# nginx proxy pass with php and relative path

Tags: php, proxy, nginx

My problem seem to be simple ...

I have 1 server on my lan 192.168.0.2 with a root path /var/www/ (apache2)
and 1 domain example.com (nginx)
and 1 subdomain bug.example.com (nginx)

and want only a proxy beetween 
`http://192.168.0.2/bugs/ --->> http://bug.example.com/`

I use a bugtracker (Mantis) in the root directory like this /var/www/bugs

this config work :

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name bug.example.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass   http://192.168.0.2/bugs/;
   }
 }
```

But i don't have access to css or images ...

Css :

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://192.168.0.2/bugs/css/default.css" />`

image :

`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/bugs/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />`

I have test a LOT OF configuration with "proxy_set_header" , "proxy_redirect" , "rewrite" ... but never with success :(

Can anybody help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a PHP problem. The site doesn't know for the redirect... As I see, it renders the CSS files with full path 192.168.0.2/bugs...
Try to find a solution how to handle this in PHP, not nginx.

Look for a configuration setting for HOST_NAME or similar in Mantis.

As for images, changing to bugs.site.com/bugs should fix them.. Otherwise you'll need to let Mantis know that it has no virtual path /bugs. Is it an Apache server behind?

UPDATE: Actually you could try stripping HOST header and sending it modified as 'bugs.site.com'... It all depends on the actuall web server/Mantis/ configuration ..

Comment: thx !! for point the php problem :) finally i have change the config_inc.php of mantis ... i think it's the better option.